# v-for and v-if not working together when data gets empty array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I faced a really silly problem today and just sharing it here:

v-for and v-if doesn't work together when its data value is `[]`. For eg:

```
ts: []

<div v-for="t in ts" :key="t" v-if="ts.length">
  Yes
</div>
<div v-else>
  No
</div>
```

See it in action here in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pyyxvkmwnx).

We can see nothing is rendered and even no error is thrown. I also tried with `v-if="ts.length > 0"` but it still renders nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not recommended to use v-for with v-if . see official docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-with-v-for

Comment: Thanks @KentV, I was forgetting about this because I came back to vue after a long time. And seeing an issue in github also didn't provide  this guide but there's working solution they found I think was old.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to separate `v-if` from `v-for` like this:

```
<div v-if="ts.length">
  <div v-for="t in ts" :key="t">
    Yes
  </div>
</div>
<div v-else>
  No
</div>
```

But this seems to be bad solution for me while others can use it as a good solution. Because I was needed to use `v-for` and `v-if` together. Its because I don't like to separate pieces from file and just need to use inside table's tr component.

Though, we agree from the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential) states: Never use v-if on the same element as v-for.